# Is There a Way to Auto-close 'App Has Stopped Responding' Messages?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-10

I have a simple batch script running constantly on a Windows 10 PC at work that performs relatively simple tasks over and over again throughout the day, basically testing certain server diagnostics while I'm working on it.

Every once in a while, the program will crash, so I have another program I downloaded that will auto-start up the program if it does crash and close.

However, there is one scenario where instead of the program just crashing and closing completely, a message box will pop up saying the program has stopped responding, with a 'Close Program' button.  In this case, the auto-start program I have thinks the program is still running, so it won't attempt to re-run the batch script.

Is there a way to auto close the program when it crashes this way, or something that will automatically click the 'Close Program' button for me when it appears?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the messages comes out when the main thread hangs for too long. It may be cleaner to spawn another thread to take care of expensive / slow computation, Windows should not bother to kill the main thread (and your program) in first place like that.